# Average duplicates from specific columns in QuerySet in Django

Tags: python, django, duplicates, django-queryset, average

I have a Django Model I am using that looks like this:

```
class FinancialAid(models.Model):
    RECEIVED_EVERY = (("J", "Jours"),
        ("S", "Semaines"),
        ("M", "Mois"))
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    Value = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=-1)
    ReceivedEvery = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True, choices=RECEIVED_EVERY)
    Exchange = models.ForeignKey('Exchange', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am able to access the information I want but I have an issue in that I often have duplicates within my QuerySet over the `Name` and `ReceivedEvery` columns but not always on the `Value` and never on the `Exchange`.

Say I have the following QuerySet expanded out:

```
financial_aid_qs = [
    (ID=1, Name="Aid1", Value=100, ReceivedEvery="M", Exchange=Exchange.objects.get(pk=1)),
    (ID=2, Name="Aid2", Value=200, ReceivedEvery="S", Exchange=Exchange.objects.get(pk=2)),
    (ID=3, Name="Aid1", Value=150, ReceivedEvery="M", Exchange=Exchange.objects.get(pk=3)),
    (ID=4, Name="Aid3", Value=100, ReceivedEvery="M", Exchange=Exchange.objects.get(pk=4))
]
```

As you can see, I have the same `Name` and `ReceivedEvery` for indexes 1 and 3. What I would like to do is get a QuerySet (or ValuesQuerySet although I seem to recall this was removed) that will contain all the different FinancialAid objects in terms of `Name` and average out the `Value` of FinancialAid objects that have the same `Name`. Ideally it would take into account the fact that `ReceivedEvery` can differ even though the `Name` is the same (This is all an average so doesn't need to be perfect which is why for the sake of this, one month is 30 days or 4 weeks).

With all this, the result should look like this:

```
financial_aid_qs = [
    (Name="Aid1", Value=125, ReceivedEvery="M"),
    (Name="Aid2", Value=200, ReceivedEvery="S"),
    (Name="Aid3", Value=100, ReceivedEvery="M")
]
```

As you can see, for `Aid1`, the value has been averaged to 125 from 100 and 150 and the other Aids haven't been modified.

Comment: In Django, you can [group your query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#values) by "Name" using `values("Name")` and then annotate to get the average "Value" by `annotate(avg_value=Avg("Value"))`. The question is what value do you want for `ReceivedEvery`? Do you want to average only if **both** `ReceivedEvery` and `Name` are the same? Or do you have another rule to aggregate `ReceivedEvery`?

Comment: Average only if `ReceivedEvery` and `Name` are the same and if they are not, calculate the correct value to have the converted value for a specific `ReceivedEvery` and then average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/aggregation/#values) to aggregate over a grouped query, e.g.:

```
financial_aid_qs = FinancialAid.objects.values("Name").annotate(avg_value=Avg("Value"))
```

This will return a queryset (when executed a list) of dictionaries:

```
financial_aid_qs = [
    {'Name': "Aid1", 'avg_value': 125},
    {'Name': "Aid2", 'avg_value': 200},
    ...
]
```

If you want to differentiate also by `ReceivedEvery`, then you just group by both values:

```
financial_aid_qs = FinancialAid.objects.values('Name', 'ReceivedEvery').annotate(...)

>>> [{'Name': "Aid1", 'ReceivedEvery': "M", 'avg_value': 125}, 
     {'Name': "Aid1", 'ReceivedEvery': "S", 'avg_value': 200}, ...]
```

Here, weekly and monthly donations will be separated for the same "Name".

Use a [**conditional expression**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) to create new values depending on others:

```
financial_aid_qs = FinancialAid.objects.annotate(
    factor=Case(
        When(ReceivedEvery="S", then=Value(4)),
        When(ReceivedEvery="M", then=Value(1)),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )).annotate(
        total=F('factor')*F('Value')
    ).values('Name').annotate(
        avg_value=Avg('total')
    )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How could I differentiate by `ReceivedEvery` but have a value for `Aid1` multiplied by 4 if it's `ReceivedEvery` is `S` and the other `Aid1` has a `ReceivedEvery` of `M`

Comment: @MaxMichel added that example.